# Loss value changes without any changes in training data or configuration in RASA NLU

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot, loss-function, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am working with RASA NLU to extract intents, and i faced a problem which is loss value changes every single time i train the model even when no new training data and no edits in config.
And these changes affect badly my results to extract intents.

I use this configuration:

language: "ar"
pipeline: 
- name: "tokenizer_whitespace"
- name: "ner_crf"
- name: "ner_synonyms"
- name: "intent_featurizer_count_vectors"
- name: "intent_classifier_tensorflow_embedding"

How to avoid such a problem, and keep the model consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, you need to set the "random_seed" parameter under "tensorflow_embedding", to a fixed number in your configurations file.